# Replace Puppet master

Tags: puppet

I have Puppet master and Puppet agent, and the agent succeed to communicate with the master. Now I want to use other machine as my Puppet master. I create another Puppet master, called master-2, and run in the agent:

```
sudo puppet agent -t --server master-2
```

that cause to error:

> certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate
>   chain for /CN=Puppet CA: master-2]

I copied the folder /var/lib/puppet/ssl from master to master-2, and now the above command succeeded.

Is there a way to prevent an agent communication with the first master? How I can remove the first master certificates from the agent and add a new certificates of master-2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new clean master-2, and copy two files from master-2 to agent:

1. Copy file "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem" from master-2 to agent, and save it as "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem".
2. Copy file "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem" from master-2 to agent, ans save it as "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem".

Delete old certificates in agent:

```
sudo find /var/lib/puppet/ssl -name <hostname>.pem -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Edit your agent's puppet.conf and add the new puppet master details in the [agent] section like below

[agent]

server=

Step 2 (optional) : If you are not copying the masters ssl certificate folder (/var/lib/puppet/ssl) , your agnet will now try to contact the server master2 and request a new certificate .You can sign the new certificate in your CA server using
 `puppet cert sign` 
 command

Comment: I use flag --server instead of your step 1.  did you tried step 2? its cause to "certificate verify failed" error. your option will work only after deleting first master certificates.